# ¿Por qué el bucle me devuelve el mismo pdf cuando lo subo de diferentes campos?

Tags: php, mysql

¿Por qué me devuelve el mismo archivo?
El bucle se repite varias veces al añadir varias imágenes.

```
//pruebafor
foreach ($_FILES['archivo']['name'] as $clave) {
    # code...
    if ($clave > 0) {
        # code...
        $nombre_tmp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'][$clave];
        $nombre = basename($_FILES['archivo']['name'][$clave]);
        move_uploaded_file($nombre_tmp, "uploadFile/$nombre");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Antes del `foreach`, coloca un `var_dump($_FILES);` y agrega el resultado en la pregunta, para analizarlo mejor.

Comment: Pues es que `$_FILES['archivo']['name']` cuántos elementos tiene? Haz el var_dump

Comment: tiene 4 elemento uno para cada imagen subida